# Multiple \usepackage vs comma separated package names

Tags: packages, best-practices

What, if anything, is the difference between

```
\usepackage{foo,bar}
```

and

```
\usepackage{foo}
\usepackage{bar}
```

Comment: Nothing more or less. They expand to the same thing before the package is loaded. the second form allows different options to be supplied. This is a duplicate, I'll find the earlier question...

Comment: Also separate package loading helps during debugging errors and to diagnose package conflicts.